# UUID type of foreign key in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8, uuid, laravel-passport, laravel-migrations

I have a table using Laravel Passport, `oauth_clients`, with a primary key of type UUID. The requirement is to create a new table with a foreign key column named `client_id` that references the primary key of the `oauth_clients` table, but I get the following error.

> Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

**Code**

```
$table->foreignUuid('oauth_client_id')->nullable()->constrained()
    ->onDelete('CASCADE')
    ->onUpdate('CASCADE');
```

**Migration/Schema**

```
$this->schema->create('oauth_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->index();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('website_color', 50)->nullable();
    $table->string('website_logo', 255)->nullable();
    $table->string('secret', 100)->nullable();
    $table->string('provider')->nullable();
    $table->text('redirect');
    $table->boolean('personal_access_client');
    $table->boolean('password_client');
});
```

Comment: What's the migration/schema for the passport oauth_clients table?

Comment: Here it is:
`$this->schema->create('oauth_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->uuid('id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->index();
$table->string('name');
$table->string('website_color',50)->nullable();
$table->string('website_logo', 255)->nullable();
$table->string('secret', 100)->nullable();
$table->string('provider')->nullable();
$table->text('redirect');
$table->boolean('personal_access_client');
$table->boolean('password_client');
});` @KarlHill

Comment: You must make sure that both UUID fields referenced have exactly the same data type.